# Firefox in Ubuntu does not load

Tags: firefox

I have just installed Ubuntu. Everything seems fine, BUT Firefox will only load Google, Bing and Gmail. All other web pages stall; just keeps loading without getting anywhere. This is hopeless because you cannot update or do anything. I have once installed Ubuntu on my harddrive, and now on a USB stick: no difference. What is the matter?

Answer (score 0):

goto ubuntu software centre and then click on the install software.Uninstall the firefox and then install it again .Restart the system .It will fix the problems.

Comment: I am afraid the problem persists. Same thing after reinstall. I should add that this problem is on a fixed internet connection. I don't have any problem with computers on wifi.

Answer (score 0):

Check your home directory. Make sure that everything in there is owned by your user, and not `root`. Be sure to check ownership on hidden files as well.

```
ls -lah ~
```

I had the same problem with Ubuntu Gnome, and had to change ownerships on `.gnome2` and `.gnome2_private`

```
chown -R username:username ~
```